# Dynamic Symbol Resolution of Executable Using LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-c++-api

I am currently using `LLVM's` `ObjectFile` (documented [here](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/ObjectFile_8h_source.html)) to represent an executable. I have successfully read in an executable to the `ObjectFile` and would like to determine which call destination addresses in my executable correspond to symbol names contained in the `symbol_iterator` obtained by a call to the `begin_dynamic_symbols()` function. Iterating over each of the symbols in the `symbol_iterator` gives me the name of each symbol and its address, but since the symbols are dynamic, the address of each symbol is -1; this indicates that the `ObjectFile` does not associate symbol names directly with their corresponding call destination addresses.

Is there any way to determine which call destination addresses map to which dynamic symbols in an `ObjectFile`? I would rather not manually calculate all the jumps through the `PLT` and `GOT` if I can avoid doing so.

Comment: I think you should ask it on the cfe-dev mailing list: http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic symbols' addresses are only calculated when the object files gets loaded into memory and linked into the program's symbol table. In general, it's impossible to determine their final address before linking.

You may be able to get the data you want using LLVM's Link-Time Optimization module instead of ObjectFile, as that does perform address linking when loading a module, if I recall correctly.

Good luck!